# ScrollView below TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I need to implement a scrollView below a tableView (not inside, i know that apple not recommend to do that). Look at the picture (needed area is black rectangle)

http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/2071/screenshot20110805at527.jpg

What you recommend to do ?

Should i add scrollView like a subview to current view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you use a scroll view there, can't you just insert a view in the tabelView tableFooterView property.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a subview of the current view, then do something like [myScrollView setFrame:]; I do recommend not IB for this, since this type of thing can be kinda awkward in it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `viewForFooterInSection` and return a `scrollEnabled` view.